# Which is the most accurate report for journeys?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We are having some trouble getting accurate sending reports of our Journeys.
As far as I know, there are at least 3 places where you can view reports of deliverability, sendings, etc. for Journeys:

- Email studio > tracking > sends > Journey Builder > Sends
- Journey Builder > History
- Analytics Builder > reports > Journey Builder Email Send Summary

I have been checking all of them and I found inconsistencies between the numbers and other data (like the time of send, which is not consistent between Journey Builder History and Email Studio Tracking, probably because a timezone bug).

I suspect that the numbers are not updated at the same time in every place. **Is this true?**

**What do you use to check out the sending numbers (emails sent, bounced, etc) for Journeys**, and

**Which one do you think is the most accurate or suitable?**

Comment: Journey Builder reporting's pretty flakey. I'd focus on the tracking statistics that are much more mature.

Comment: Thanks @Macca. I tend to check tracking statistics too, but I got a bit pissed when I found the timezone discrepancy. Apparently the "time sent" was not accurate with the timezone we have set up.

Comment: Tracking data is reading off the data views. These store data in CST (which is GMT-6)...they won't be reformatting to yours or your accounts time zone. Use the Journey Builder History to help error handling - not as a source of truth for anything. Both your other 2 reports should be relatively accurate...I have seen issues in both historically from time to time but they are largely accurate

Comment: Thank you so much @JarrettBush.